# How to recursively add id tag using jQuery to ul & li elements, according to their depth within the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, recursion

How to give unique id attributes and reflect the same within all `ul` `li` elements according to their depth/level within the parent list.

- first `ul` should have `id="u1"`

  - first `li` within that `ul` should have `id="u1l1"`
  - next `li` within that `ul` should have `id="u1l2"`
  - next `li` within that `ul` should have `id="u1l3"`

    - `ul` within that should have `id="u1l3-u1"`
    - next `ul` within that should have `id="u1l3-u2"`

      - `li` within that should have `id="u1l3-u2l1"`
      - next `li` should have `id="u1l3-u2l2"`
      - and so on...

To make things clearer, here's a sample code that I generated using a spreadsheet program...

For example the following code:

```
<div id="listz">
<ul>
    <li><span>Colors</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Primary Colors</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Yellow</li>
                    <li><span>Red</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Red</li>
                            <li>Fire Brick</li>
                            <li><span>Salmon</span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Dark Salmon</li>
                                    <li>Light Salmon</li>
                                    <li>Salmon</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Coral</li>
                            <li>Crimson</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Blue</li>
                </ul>
            <li><span>Secondary Colors</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Orange</li>
                    <li>Green</li>
                    <li>Purple</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Earth Colors</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>White</li>
                    <li>Black</li>
                    <li>Gray</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Stationary</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Books
                <ul>
                    <li>Ruled Books</li>
                    <li>Unruled Books</li>
                    <li><span>Graph Books</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Cartesian Graphs</li>
                            <li>Isometric Graphs</li>
                            <li>Logarithmic Graphs</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Pens</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Ball Pens</li>
                    <li>Fountain Pens</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Eraser</li>
            <li>Paper Weight</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Furniture</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>foo fighters</li>
</ul>
```

should become:

```
<div id="listz">
<ul id="u1">
<li id="u1l1"><span>Stationary</span>
    <ul id="u1l1-u1">
        <li id="u1l1-u1l1">Books
            <ul id="u1l1-u1l1-u1">
                <li id="u1l1-u1l1-u1l1">Ruled Books</li>
                <li id="u1l1-u1l1-u1l2">Unruled Books</li>
                <li id="u1l1-u1l1-u1l3"><span>Graph Books</span>
                    <ul id="u1l1-u1l1-u1l3-u1">
                        <li id="u1l1-u1l1-u1l3-u1l1">Cartesian Graphs</li>
                        <li id="u1l1-u1l1-u1l3-u1l2">Isometric Graphs</li>
                        <li id="u1l1-u1l1-u1l3-u1l3">Logarithmic Graphs</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="u1l1-u1l2"><span>Pens</span>
            <ul id="u1l1-u1l2-u1">
                <li id="u1l1-u1l2-u1l1">Ball Pens</li>
                <li id="u1l1-u1l2-u1l2">Fountain Pens</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="u1l1-u1l3">Eraser</li>
        <li id="u1l1-u1l4">Paper Weight</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="u1l2">Furniture</li>
<li id="u1l3"><span>Colors</span>
    <ul id="u1l3-u1">
        <li id="u1l3-u1l1"><span>Primary Colors</span>
            <ul id="u1l3-u1l1-u1">
                <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l1">Yellow</li>
                <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2"><span>Red</span>
                    <ul id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1">
                        <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1l1">Red</li>
                        <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1l2">Fire Brick</li>
                        <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1l3"><span>Salmon</span>
                            <ul id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1l3-u1">
                                <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1l3-u1l1">Dark Salmon</li>
                                <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1l3-u1l2">Light Salmon</li>
                                <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1l3-u1l3">Salmon</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1l4">Coral</li>
                        <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l2-u1l5">Crimson</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="u1l3-u1l1-u1l3">Blue</li>
            </ul>
        <li id="u1l3-u1l2"><span>Secondary Colors</span>
            <ul id="u1l3-u1l2-u1">
                <li id="u1l3-u1l2-u1l1">Orange</li>
                <li id="u1l3-u1l2-u1l2">Green</li>
                <li id="u1l3-u1l2-u1l3">Purple</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="u1l3-u1l3"><span>Earth Colors</span>
            <ul id="u1l3-u1l3-u1">
                <li id="u1l3-u1l3-u1l1">White</li>
                <li id="u1l3-u1l3-u1l2">Black</li>
                <li id="u1l3-u1l3-u1l3">Gray</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="u1l4">foo</li>
<li id="u1l3">bar</li>
<li>foo fighters</li>
```

Here's what I've tried:

```js
$("ul").each(function (i)
{
  $(this).attr("id","u"+(i+1));
  $(this).prepend("<span>u"+(i+1)+"</span>");
  $("li", this).each(function (j)
  {
    $(this).attr("id","l"+(j+1));
    $(this).prepend("<span>l"+(j+1)+"</span>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listz">
        <ul>
            <li><span>Colors</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Primary Colors</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Yellow</li>
                            <li><span>Red</span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Red</li>
                                    <li>Fire Brick</li>
                                    <li><span>Salmon</span>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Dark Salmon</li>
                                            <li>Light Salmon</li>
                                            <li>Salmon</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>Coral</li>
                                    <li>Crimson</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Blue</li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><span>Secondary Colors</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Orange</li>
                            <li>Green</li>
                            <li>Purple</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Earth Colors</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>White</li>
                            <li>Black</li>
                            <li>Gray</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Stationary</span>
                <ul>
                    <li>Books
                        <ul>
                            <li>Ruled Books</li>
                            <li>Unruled Books</li>
                            <li><span>Graph Books</span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Cartesian Graphs</li>
                                    <li>Isometric Graphs</li>
                                    <li>Logarithmic Graphs</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><span>Pens</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Ball Pens</li>
                            <li>Fountain Pens</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Eraser</li>
                    <li>Paper Weight</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Furniture</li>
            <li>foo</li>
            <li>bar</li>
            <li>foo fighters</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: xy problem why do you need so many ids?why not use dom traversal functions?

Comment: Just an experiment to try out looping in jQuery. Just like we write code in C for Star patterns. No one uses the star patterns in real life but are good for coding procedure and getting a grasp on the language...

Comment: so you want to do a  collective experiment with us? what have you tried?

Comment: added my trial; sorry I don't want to do any experiment it's just what popped into my head and I wanted to see what's the best way to tackle it in jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function

```js
addIdPartial('', $('#listz'));

function addIdPartial(id, li) {
  if ($(li).find('> ul > li').length) {
    $(li).find('> ul > li').each(function(i, v) {
      pid = id + '-u1'
      if(id == '') pid = 'u1';
      $(this).parent().attr('id', pid);
      var lid = pid + 'l' + (i+1);
      $(this).attr('id', lid);
      addIdPartial(lid, this);
    })
  }

}
```

```css
ul:before, li:before {
 content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listz">
  <ul>
    <li><span>Colors</span>
      <ul>
        <li><span>Primary Colors</span>
          <ul>
            <li>Yellow</li>
            <li><span>Red</span>
              <ul>
                <li>Red</li>
                <li>Fire Brick</li>
                <li><span>Salmon</span>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Dark Salmon</li>
                    <li>Light Salmon</li>
                    <li>Salmon</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Coral</li>
                <li>Crimson</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Blue</li>
          </ul>
          <li><span>Secondary Colors</span>
            <ul>
              <li>Orange</li>
              <li>Green</li>
              <li>Purple</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span>Earth Colors</span>
            <ul>
              <li>White</li>
              <li>Black</li>
              <li>Gray</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Stationary</span>
        <ul>
          <li>Books
            <ul>
              <li>Ruled Books</li>
              <li>Unruled Books</li>
              <li><span>Graph Books</span>
                <ul>
                  <li>Cartesian Graphs</li>
                  <li>Isometric Graphs</li>
                  <li>Logarithmic Graphs</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span>Pens</span>
            <ul>
              <li>Ball Pens</li>
              <li>Fountain Pens</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Eraser</li>
          <li>Paper Weight</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Furniture</li>
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>foo fighters</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the solution. Maybe I shouldn't have posted this question on StackOverflow; Is there any other forum/SO community where I can post Code experiments/challanges. Sorry, for posting it here, didn't know it wasn't allowed...